# Webdav log analyzer

Tags: linux, webdav

Are there any monitoring tools for webda

1. Are there any monitoring tools for webdav (logfiles)?
2. What analyzers are available for webdav logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method to monitor these files is to use the command line...

```
tail <logfilename here>
```

If you continue to run tail against the file, it will show you the newest entries whenever they appear.  Load cygwin if you are trying to do this on a windows box.

Now if you want a tool to analyze these files I recommend using something like Splunk or AppManager from NetIQ.

[Splunk is Here](http://www.splunk.com/download?ac=ga0108_s_logmanagement&_kk=log%20monitoring&_kt=8f847ad7-9cda-4906-985e-855255534089&gclid=CPnt5Y7O_ZsCFdZM5QodVA1Y_Q)

[App Manager can be found Here](http://www.netiq.com/)

Both have the ability to dig deep into the log data.

Answer (score 1):

A great general log file viewer is [LogExpert](http://www.log-expert.de/), see also the [Stackoverflow Best Tail GUI question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133821/the-best-tail-gui).